# How to create a horizontal scrollable list?

Tags: iphone, listview, horizontallist

I am wondering what the best approach is for creating a horizontal list with custom buttons. I read there is no native control for that:

I am considering a UIView with a scroll view inside. On this scrollview I visualize my array of button objects.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) with paging and only horizontal scrolling should give you a good start.

Look at a [PageControl example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795) from the iPhone SDK.